# Cursor.moveToNext without moveToFirst

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Will the next code work as expected?

```
Cursor c = db.query(tableName, requestedColumns, condition,
        conditionParams, null, null, sortOrder);
while(c.moveToNext())   {
     //do stuff with rows
}
```

The examples I found so far suggest calling `c.moveToFirst()` prior looping, but is it really necessary?

Comment: Also make sure to close the cursor when you are done with it, after the while loop. GL

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it will work, `moveToNext` actually call `moveToFirst`

Comment: moveToNext moves to next, but if the starting position is -1 so first call of moveToNext acts as moveToFirst

Comment: Yes moveToNext calls  moveToPosition(mPos + 1) and moveToFirst calls  moveToPosition(0). So if you are the start -1, then they behave the same.

Comment: what if the cursor doesn't have any records or rows in it. Wont it give any error?

Comment: @Sudhir In  that case it will return `false`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will work, the first moveToNext() will point the cursor to the first entry of the result set, (if the result set has values)

Answer (score 2):

A late answer, but maybe useful to others finding this page. I've been using an: "if () do {  } while();" loop. The "moveToFirst()" function returns false if no rows were returned in the cursor. The "moveToNext()" function returns false when past end of the cursor:

```
Cursor c = db.query(......);

if (c.moveToFirst()) do {
   data = c.getString(0) // eg. get value from first column in cursor
   // do something more
} while (c.moveToNext());

c.close();
```